# Quartz - problems with log4j at application level

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j, quartz-scheduler, weblogic11g

I am using Weblogic 116, Ejb3.0 , quartz-all 1.8.5.

I have issues with quartz when I am deleting the log4j jar from the lib directory of the server.

The reason I cant have log4j there (under lib) it's because I want each deployment in Weblogic  to have it's own loggings. so each deployment has it's own log4j jar.

Of coarse that If put back the `log4j.jar` to the `server/lib` dir then quartz work fine but then I cant have seperate logs for my deployments.

When I remove the log4j jar from lib this is the error I get from quartz:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.(StaticLoggerBinder.java:83)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.(StaticLoggerBinder.java:53)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:122)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:112)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)

..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options.

1) Deploy log4j.jar as a Shared Library or an Optional Package.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13706/libraries.htm#i1064674
Then reference log4j from your application.  If your application is an EAR, then you can just reference it as a Shared Library from weblogic-application.xml with a library-ref element and when your application is deployed the log4j.jar gets added to APP-INF/lib of the EAR.  If you have a WAR, then you can reference it as an Optional Package by modifying the META-INF/manifest.mf file:
  Extension-List: log4jjar
  log4jjar-Extension-Name: log4j

Where log4j is the name of the deployment of the Shared Library/Optional Package

2) Use filtering classloaders in your previously deployed apps.

Comment: I have solved it by adding the referenced jars to the ear folder in my deployment.